# calling inject only passing it a symbol

Tags: ruby

Could someone explain this with an example of how it is useful.

Specifically I am having an issue with how you accumulate something (an array would be nice) when you change scope into a method..

e.g.

```
def modify(value)
  ...code ....
end

an_array.inject(:modify)
```

How can I get an accumulator (above), or something that is passing a message along. The value returned is the last value to come out of modify. But modify only gets each value in the array. It doesn't get the message. (below) passing message to the .... code ...

```
an_array.inject(0) { |message,element| .... code .... }
```

Comment: Would you be able to give a bit more info about the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Using `inject` with only a symbol:

```
[*1..5].inject(:+) #=> 15
```

The above translates to:

```
[*1..5].inject { |sum, num| sum + num }
```

This is what the docs have to say on the subject (emphasis added):

> Combines all elements of enum by applying ***a binary operation,
>   specified by a block or a symbol*** that names a method or operator

I'm happy to update my answer once you clarify the second part of your question a bit (e.g. what do you mean by "changing scope" in this context?).